# It is possible to store value from $_SESSION after <a href=""> click

Tags: wordpress, session

I try to  to store the value of $ _SESSION after clicking a href = '/ page' and add this value to body id, but trace it when I go to another subpage

```
$url = 'https://page.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$wcag = 'https://page.com/example/';
$no_wcag = 'https://page.com/';
$sesja;
if (($url == $wcag) || ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == $wcag)) {
    $_SESSION["usertemplate_css"] = 'wcag-theme';


} elseif (($url == $no_wcag) || ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == $no_wcag)) {
    $_SESSION["usertemplate_css"] = '';

}
else {
    $_SESSION["usertemplate_css"] = '';

}

<body <?php body_class(); ?> id="<?php echo $_SESSION["usertemplate_css"]; ?>">
```

Comment: did you remember to session_start()?

Comment: yes, i try with session_start(); and still nothing

Comment: Excuse me, but why do you echo this value inside `id="..."`, instead of adding it to the body class? I don't think that does what you want it to do. I think what you want is this: `<?php body_class( $_SESSION["usertemplate_css"] ); ?>`
If that doesn't work, fill `$_SESSION["usertemplate_css"]` with a specific class name for each branch to debug which branch your code took. Currently, you cannot discern whether the elseif or else was used.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I was thinking about adding an id, not body class